# SQL DateFormat Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, formatting, sql-server-2000

Is there a function in SQL that formats a date when given the date and format string?

Similar to how .NET's `DateTime.ToString(string format)` method works?

I'd like to be able to call something like `FORMAT(@myDateTime, 'ddMMMyyyy')` and have it give me a string formatted as such.

I know the convert function works but it doesn't quite cover all formats. As an example, SQL can do "dd MMM yyyy" but not "ddMMMyyyy"

Comment: I guess `CONVERT` will do the job. Which format you are looking for?

Comment: Which version of sql server (and please edit tags too!)? SQL2012 upwards come with a new format-function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: @Shnugo I've just updated it with the SQL 2000 tag

Comment: SQL 2000? Poor boy :-)  below there are some answers concerning CONVERT...

Comment: A better question would be why are you relying on SQL Server to do your formatting? This is a job for the [presentation layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_layer).

Comment: Write your own function using existing datetime functions and string parsing functions.

Comment: @GarethD Not by choice. There is no "presentation" layer

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no direct function that will convert date in format passed by you if you are on older SQL version. [Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh213505.aspx) function is available starting from SQL 2012.

You can use convert function but it may not always suit your need.

Refer this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186724.aspx

To answer your question, this will give you date in DD-MMM-YYYY Format:

```
select REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,getdate(),106), ' ','-'), ',','')
```

For DDMMMYYYY format:

```
select REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,getdate(),106), ' ','-'), ',',''),'-','')
```

Also, you can check the date formats supported by convert function using this:

```
select convert(varchar, getdate(), 101)
select convert(varchar, getdate(), 102)
select convert(varchar, getdate(), 103)
select convert(varchar, getdate(), 104)
select convert(varchar, getdate(), 105)
select convert(varchar, getdate(), 106)
select convert(varchar, getdate(), 107)
select convert(varchar, getdate(), 108)
select convert(varchar, getdate(), 109)
select convert(varchar, getdate(), 110)
select convert(varchar, getdate(), 111)
select convert(varchar, getdate(), 112)
select convert(varchar, getdate(), 113)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this isn't flexible enough for me. I may need spaces for one instance and not for the next. (dd MMM yyyy vs ddMMMyyyy for example).

Comment: Go for a user defined functions to achieve level of flexibility you want.